# Change console size in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible in Eclipse to resize the bottom panel to the entire width of the screen, without hiding the project explorer, as IntelliJ does?

I have this:

[image: Eclipse console]

And I would like this:

[image: IntelliJ console]

Comment: I think you just have to move the Project Explorer panel to the left of your text editor. This way it will be above the console and not on its left anymore, thus letting it take the whole width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in comments, the *Console* view will take the entire width if the *Project Explorer* view, which is currently on its left, is moved to the left of the text editor. This way, the *Project Explorer* will be above the *Console* as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of Eclipse IDE with the Console view taking all the width]

> Note: a view can be moved by [drag-and-dropping its title bar](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-3e.htm).